# Cloudformation Stack not receiving signal from userdata in EC2 Launch Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my template, I'm provisioning an ASG that uses an [EC2 Launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-asg-launch-template.html)

In the [`UserData`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata.html#cfn-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata-userdata) section, I do a [`cfn-init`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) to provision the instance, which works fine.

However when I do the [`cfn-signal`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html) command, the command is successful (exit code of 0), but the Cloudformation stack never receives it, and the stack creation/update fails with `Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.`

When I check Cloudtrail, I see that the `SignalResource` API call was completed, signaling the correct Stack and resource with a `SUCCESS`, (but a `responseElements` of `null`)

Excerpt from my Cloudformation template:

```
Resources:
  MyLaunchTemplate:
      Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
      Metadata:
        'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
          configSets:
            # lots-o-stuff to be done by cfn-init
      Properties:
        LaunchTemplateData:
          # Remove other attributes for brevity
          UserData:
            Fn::Base64:
              !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -x
                yum update -y
                # gather ENI
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -c install \
                  --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                  --resource MyLaunchTemplate \
                  --region ${AWS::Region}
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
                  --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                  --resource MyAsg \
                  --region ${AWS::Region}
                echo $?
        LaunchTemplateName: my-launch-template
  MyAsg:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
      CreationPolicy:
        AutoScalingCreationPolicy:
          MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent: 100
        ResourceSignal:
          Count: 1
          Timeout: PT10M
      UpdatePolicy:
        AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
          WillReplace: true
      Properties:
        # Remove other attributes for brevity
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateId: !Ref MyLaunchTemplate
          Version: !GetAtt MyLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Amazon Linux AMI version is not the latest and `cfn-signal` script isn't installed on the instance. Bootstrap the EC2 instance using [aws-cfn-bootstrap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html) package.

Add `yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap` in `UserData` section.

Another possible cause could be that the value of the `Timeout` property for the [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html) attribute is too low. Make sure that the value is high enough for tasks to run before the `cfn-signal` script sends signals to AWS CloudFormation resources.

If it still doesn't work, then do check out [AWS Troubleshooting Guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-failed-signal/) for this issue.

Comment: `Timeout` is okay at 10 minutes (The signal is sent within 2 minutes of the instance launching as seen in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`). I confirmed I was using the latest Amazon Linux 2 AMI, and see in Cloudtrail logs that the sender was `"userAgent": "CfnTools/1.4-31 (Linux-4.14.146-120.181.amzn2.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5) python/2.7.16"`

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced a similar issue recently. It seems like cfn-signals don’t work with launch template for some reason. For test purposes I changed my launch template to a launch configuration and the cfn signal worked totally fine. It’s weird why AWS don’t support launch templates.