# Is CloudFormation signalling broken in the context of creation and update policies for auto scaling groups using launch templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've hit a dead-end on my debugging and I'd appreciate any insight y'all could provide.

I setup an auto scaling group (ASG) of size 1 using launch templates in a public subnet. The ASG is configured with a creation policy and an update policy. The instance user data invokes cfn-signal after cfn-init has completed.

During my initial deployment, CloudFormation pauses for the signals, but ultimately times out and a rollback occurs. I set a pause time of 10 minutes in the creation policy, which should be more than enough time. To debug, I deploy again, ssh into the instance during the pause after the EC2 instance checks have passed, I check the logs with

`sudo grep -ni 'error\|failure' $(sudo find /var/log -name cfn\* -or -name cloud-init\*)`

, and I find no errors. cfn-init.log shows cfn-signal transmitting a SUCCESS status, and cfn-wire.log shows the associated HTTP response with a 200 status. I then attempt to manually send the signal, and stdout shows the following, indicating that signal has already been sent:

```
[DEBUG] Signaling resource <ASG_LOGICAL_ID> in stack <STACK_NAME> with unique ID <INSTANCE_ID> and status SUCCESS
ValidationError: Signal with ID <INSTANCE_ID> for resource <ASG_LOGICAL_ID> already exists.  Signals may only be updated with a FAILURE status.
```

CloudFormation stack event logs on AWS management console shows that the ASG is still in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. The transmission of the success signal is not causing the transition to CREATE_COMPLETE.

To test the update policy, I commented out the creation policy, deployed, changed the key pair name in the launch template to another one that also works so I could trigger the update policy, and deployed again. Instance in ASG gets brought down (minimum instance in service is 0 in auto scaling rolling update policy), and its replacement gets brought up. At this point, CloudFormation pauses and waits for signal, and I repeat my debugging steps above only to encounter the same results as above.

Here are more details that may be of use:

- Creation Policy was configured like so:

```
"CreationPolicy" : {
  "AutoScalingCreationPolicy" : {
    "MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent" : 100,
  },
  "ResourceSignal" : {    
    "Count" : 1,
    "Timeout" : "PT10M"
  }
}
```

- Instance role has a principal policy with the following actions allowed:

  - cloudformation:DescribeStackResource
  - cloudformation:SignalResource
- The instance is configured to be a NAT instance and it does work. I tested it as suggested here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#nat-test-configuration
- Logical ID of ASG is passed to resource option of cfn-signal
- Logical ID of launch template is passed to resource option of cfn-init
- Amazon Linux 2 AMI

  - Made sure to install aws-cfn-bootstrap
- In the launch template, I specified an external network interface to be used as the default network interface of the sole instance. Here's details about that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-launch-template.html#change-network-interface

Comment: Can you show your wait condition configuration? While debugging the logs, have you tried manually running cfn-signal?

Comment: Pretty sure 'error\|failure' is wrong. The backslash makes the pipe a literal.

Comment: @jordanm I've edited my post to answer your question. Yes, I have.

Comment: @RodrigoM Good eye. I'll double check for error/failure messages. I ran that command because it was suggested here, verbatim, except for the sudo I appended to the beginning: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-failed-signal/

Comment: @RodrigoM It appears the 'error\|failure' is correct. In basic regular expressions for grep, certain characters, such as '|', lose their meaning unless backslashed: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html

Comment: @bomb-omb I would recommend adding `set -x` to the script that you are running cfn-signal from and viewing the debug output in the logs from that. The wait config looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you show how your calling cfn-signal? How are you passing the stack id to the command?

Comment: @jordanm I added `set -x` and didn't find anything abnormal. Both the expanded stack name and ASG logical ID match those displayed by the CloudFormation stack event logs on the management console. I manually signaled a success and the same validation error as in the post was exhibited. I also tried manually signalling a failure, but the resource state remained in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS despite a "successful" transmission, just like with the success signal.

Comment: It seems I'm not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925187/cloudformation-stack-not-receiving-signal-from-userdata-in-ec2-launch-template. If the cause is truly on AWS's end, I'm astonished by how long it's been unresolved because of how fundamental cfn-signal is and AWS pushing for adoption of launch template over launch configuration.